# Naive bayes python - php - javascript (node)

Tags: php, python, algorithm, bayesian-networks, categorization

I'm trying to create a data extractor algoritm from group buying sites to build an agregator for deals. First I need an algorith that will extract title,price,discount,image,coordinates.

I have solution for image,discount and coordinates but for title and category recognition I need to create an naive bayes algorithm. What is best language to do this: php? python? js? node.js?

What do I need to create an algorithm?

An model with examples?
etc. I give 100 titles and then give all web content from some sites and do script can recognize what sentence is a title?

So I dont need a word. I need an sentence and that sentence is sometimes `<h1> - <h2>` and somethings other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seriously cannot understand much of your post, but since naive bayes is something very commonly requested here on SO, I created a simple piece of code which can be used without any additional library (like NLTK) in python (and is also way faster than NLTK for training). You can find it [here](https://github.com/luke14free/sentipy).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any experience with AI algorithms and you want to add some algoritm that can learn I suggest you should use google prediction API:

https://developers.google.com/prediction/